# Disable link action when Making AJAX Call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link UNDO that call my controller `Restore()`.

Thing is I can't disable link calling the controller.

So, it opens it with a Json response instead of staying in the same page.

Here is my code:

The link:

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-lg-8'>" + data.msg + "</div>
   <div class='col-lg-4' align='right'>
      <a class='undo' href='"+ url+ '/' + dataId + "/restore' 'data-restore' =" + dataId +" >
        <span class='undo_link'>UNDO</span> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The AJAX Call that should cancel the Link:

```
$('.undo').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // ... All my ajax stuff.
}
```

Any Idea why is doesn't respect: `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: And, since when can you do this in HTML: `<a href='"+ url+ '/' + dataId + "/restore' 'data-restore' =" + dataId +" >`?

Comment: this is JS code! I call it from noty.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because you're calling `preventDefault()` on the `span` element, yet the link that's followed is on the parent `a` element. This means you either need to use `stopPropagation()`, to stop the link being fired on the `a`:

```
$('.undo_link').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // All my ajax stuff.
});
```

Or alternatively hook to the click event of the `a` itself by putting the `undo_link` class on that element:

```
<a href="' + url + '/' + dataId + '/restore" data-restore="' + dataId + '" class="undo_link">
    UNDO
</a>
```

Also note that if the element is appended after the DOM has loaded you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.undo_link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // All my ajax stuff.
});
```

Comment: You're right! I updated my code but it still have the same behaviour

Comment: it seems that $('.undo').click(function (e) {} is never called

Comment: When I hardcode this: <a class="undo" href="#"><span class="undo_link">UNDO</span> </a> it works, but when I call it from JS, i t doesn't work anymore :( Don't know why

Comment: Is the element added after the DOM has loaded? If so you need to use `$(document).on('click', '.undo', function(e) ...`

Comment: Tx! Now I got it working! Please include it in the answer to accept it!